# Json data with collection of objects gets mapped as observable instead of observable array

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, collections, mapping

On my page, I want to receive a viewmodel of a user account via Json. The data consists of some user details such as real name and email addresse etc. Besides that, I also need to show (and change) the groups which the specific user is a member of, and a list of all available user groups to select additional ones for the user.

The data gets loaded properly and the user details show up as expected. For the group assignment, I created two list boxes. The first one shows the currently assigned groups, the other one shows all existing groups. I want to use two buttons to move a selected item from the "All Groups" list to the "Selected Groups" list ("Add to selection") and another one to remove an item from the "Selected Groups" list and put it back into the "All Groups" list.

Both lists get populated correctly. When I look into my viewModel at runtime, I can see that `viewModel.AllGroups()` is an observable with a number of *group* objects in its `_latestValues` (a group object consists of an *Id* and a *GroupName*). I can also properly access them directly, e.g. with a button click for testing that triggers

```
alert(viewModel.AllGroups()[0].GroupName());
```

This gives the right text, so basically everything is in place. But when I try to manually add a group object to `SelectedGroups` collection, it seems that `viewModel.SelectedGroups` and `viewModel.AllGroups` do not have `.push` or `.remove` because they are not an observable array but just an observable!?

Here's my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel;

    $(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $.getJSON('/Admin/GetEditWebUserData?Id=@WebUserId', function (data) {
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            Selected = viewModel.SelectedGroups();

            viewModel.addToSelection = function () {
                viewModel.SelectedGroups().push({ GroupName: 'Test Group', Id: '123' });
            }

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('data'));
        });
    });
</ script>
```

... and here's the HTML part with the bindings:

```
<div id="data">
    <div class="WebUserGroupEditBox">
        Member of:
        <select size="5" data-bind="options: SelectedGroups(), optionsText: 'GroupName', optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
        <button data-bind="click: removeFromSelection">remove from selection</button>
    </div>
    <div class="WebUserGroupEditBox">
        Available groups:
        <select multiple="multiple" size="5" data-bind="options: AllGroups(), optionsText: 'GroupName', optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
        <button data-bind="click: addToSelection">add to selection</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the *add to selection* button, I get an error telling me that `.push` does not exist. I think this might me an issue with the mapping. Is there something I can do other than implementing the mapping on my own?

**Update:** This is some Json data (sniffed directly from the server response):

```
{
   "FirstName":"Rob",
   "LastName":"Smith",
   "UserName":"rsmith",
   "Email":"rsmith@test.com",
   "SelectedGroups":null,
   "AllGroups":[
      {
         "Id":0,
         "GroupName":"Managers",
         "AllowCommands":true,
         "AllowParameters":true
      },
      {
         "Id":1,
         "GroupName":"Guests",
         "AllowCommands":false,
         "AllowParameters":false
      }
   ]
}
```

**Solution:**

The problem was not the mapping itself, but the server-side code that constructs the Json data. As nemesv pointed out in his comment, there needs to be an empty array instead of null when there are no items, so that the mapping plugin properly recognizes the structure of the data.

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON payload what you receive from the server? Just log out the `data` before calling `ko.mapping.fromJS`

Comment: Please have a look at my updated post.

Comment: What is the exact error message what are you getting? The `SelectedGroups` in null in your response so the mapping plugin does not know that is array... can you change the server side to send an empty array `"SelectedGroups":[]` instead?

Comment: You are right, that's the problem. When SelectedGroups is not empty, the "Test Group" gets added to the list. Thanks!

Comment: @nemesv Can you add that as a solution so people don't have to trawl through comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your JSON coming form the server:

```
"SelectedGroups":null,
```

Because your property is `null` the mapping plugin has no idea that you want an array here it just create a `ko.observable` for you.

To fix it you need to change your server side to send an empty array instead of `null`:

```
"SelectedGroups": [],
```

in this case the mapping plugin will create an empty `ko.observableArray`.

However if you cannot change the server side you can also tell the mapping plugin how to map the `"SelectedGroups"` property using the [`create` mapping option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing-object-construction-using-create):

```
var mapping = {
    "SelectedGroups": {
        create: function(options){
            if (!options.data) // no data from the server return an empty array
                return ko.observableArray();
            // SelectedGroups is not empty continue the mapping
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        }
    }
};

var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7fds/).